# abort functionality implementation using signals

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, signals

Below is the example of `abort` functionality implementation using `signals` as given in "Advanced Programming in Unix". Few doubts in the below code -

---

```
void    abort(void)         /* POSIX-style abort() function */
{
    sigset_t           mask;
    struct sigaction   action;

    /*
     * Caller can't ignore SIGABRT, if so reset to default.
     */
    sigaction(SIGABRT, NULL, &action);
    if (action.sa_handler == SIG_IGN) {
        action.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
        sigaction(SIGABRT, &action, NULL);
    }
    if (action.sa_handler == SIG_DFL)
        fflush(NULL);           /* flush all open stdio streams */

    /*
     * Caller can't block SIGABRT; make sure it's unblocked.
     */
    sigfillset(&mask);
    sigdelset(&mask, SIGABRT);  /* mask has only SIGABRT turned off */
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL);
    kill(getpid(), SIGABRT);    /* send the signal */ **STEP 1**

    /*
     * If we're here, process caught SIGABRT and returned.
     */
    fflush(NULL);               /* flush all open stdio streams */
    action.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
    sigaction(SIGABRT, &action, NULL);  /* reset to default */
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL);  /* just in case ... */
    kill(getpid(), SIGABRT);                /* and one more time */ **STEP 2**
    exit(1);    /* this should never be executed ... */
}
```

---

**Question**
a. When we send the first `kill` with `SIGABRT` (marked by Step 1), why are we expecting the code to continue to next line? (see the comment - '*If we're here, process caught SIGABRT and returned*'  )

b. Why do we need to deliver `kill` signal again (in Step 2) and then `exit(1)` is not supposed to be hit. (refer comment in the code)

Comment: Regarding b) I think you might receive better answers by the original author. It's probably just "hell just froze"/"just in case"-thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most programs don't do anything particular with `SIGABRT`.

But some weird programs could install their own signal handler on `SIGABRT`, and the `abort` function should still work, even for them.

So most programs -those not catching `SIGABRT`- won't go past step 1 (because the default behavior for `SIGABRT` is to dump core, according to [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) ...).

The few programs who do catch `SIGABRT` will go till step 2 (if calling your `abort`). At that point, the default behavior of `SIGABRT` has been reinstalled. So the program dump core at step 2. And the final `exit(1)` cannot be reached.

Comment: Yours is the one that is complete. I actually missed the reinstallation of a default handler. Deleting my answer :)